# Is 'exercise bugs' an expression?

Tags: terminology, bug

Is there an expression in programming that something will 'exercise bugs'?

I have seen this written before but I don't know what it means.

Comment: *[citation needed]* -- I don't think this is a thing.  You don't exercise bugs; you *fail an assertion.*

Comment: Exercise or exorcise?

Comment: Bugs aren't *exercised*, they're *reproduced*. *Exercising* is something that you do to every branch of your program's control flow, to achieve coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Exercising bugs would be a pointless activity.  What you would do instead is *exercise the program to uncover bugs.*

You can do this a number of different ways:

1. Throw a lot of realistic data at the code, and see which data permutations break.
2. Use a tool like Microsoft Moles to exercise each branch of the code.
3. Hit the code with a stress tester to see how it behaves under high load.

Integration tests are a form of exercising code.  Unit tests tend to operate in a "sterile lab" environment; running the code in its normal working environment can uncover bugs that didn't appear during unit testing.

Comment: "Exercising bugs would be a pointless activity." - Consider the case where a bug is reported and then you write test cases (at any level - unit, integration, system) for that bug. You may uncover more ways to produce the bug than reported. Couldn't you say that these test cases "exercise the bug"?

Comment: @ThomasOwens: "Exercising the bug" isn't a thing.  The only Google Hit for "exercise the bug programming" is this question.